# problem while using server side component inside clientside component in next js 13 app directory

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I need something like this. The parent comp of this `clientsidecomponent` is page directory
How can I implement **page.tsx** with the given requirements*/}

```
const ClientComponent = () => {
    return ({
        data.map(d => (
            {/* @ts-expect-error Async Server Component */ }
            <ServerComponent props = { d } /> ))
    })
}

export default ClientComponent



export default async function ServerComponent({ prop }) {
    const res = await getProductsData(prop)
    const proData = await res
    return <>
        {proData.map(
            d => (
                <img src={d.img_src} height={30} width={30} />
            )
        )}
    </>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Server Component as a child or prop of a Client Component. [Importing Server Components into Client Components](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#importing-server-components-into-client-components)